# Turn PI screen portrait

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

Where can I put this command to make sure the PI will execute it every time on startup.

xrandr -o left

I have tried with startup.sh and /boot/config.txt but still no luck

Comment: What is startup.sh? You can't just insert random commands in config.txt - it is a config file NOT an interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the desktop manager has started before you can rotate the screen. `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` would be an appropriate place to add this command.

I'm a bit surprised the Pi didn't remember the changes for you. I don't use rotation, but then I changed the resolution in the screen config, it was preserved after a reboot.

Comment: thank you that worked. have a nice day

Comment: @EnricoPretorius If you are satisfied with this answer, please indicate that by ticking the big checkmark on the left.

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev now I have different issue, we wrote a small application for end-users to rotate the screen, so they would open the application and click the rotation they need. If I change the orientation manually in /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart  it works great, so in the autostart I just added a comment "xrandr -o normal" and the only thing our application does is change the normal to left or right, but if we use our application to do this and the PI reboot it comes with black screen and no desktop. What would causes this to happen.

Comment: @EnricoPretorius Hard to say without knowing what your application does exactly. Is it running `xrandr` (and how?), is it editing the `autostart` file (again, how?), or something else?